# News site scrape with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape some news. I have a larger list of 3k articles from this site, selected by criteria, and (considering I am new to Python) I came out with this script to scrape them:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv
# get the URL list
list1 = []

a = 'https://www.dnes.bg/sofia/2019/03/13/borisov-se-pohvali-prihodite-ot-gorivata-sa-sys-7-poveche.404467'
b = 'https://www.dnes.bg/obshtestvo/2019/03/13/pazim-ezika-si-pravopis-pod-patronaja-na-radeva.404462'
c = 'https://www.dnes.bg/politika/2019/01/03/politikata-nekanen-gost-na-praznichnata-novogodishna-trapeza.398091'
list1.append(a)
list1.append(b)
list1.append(c)
# define the variables
#url = "https://www.dnes.bg/politika/2019/01/03/politikata-nekanen-gost-na-praznichnata-novogodishna-trapeza.398091"
list2 = list1 #[0:10]
#type(list2)

href = []
title = []
subtitle = []
time = []
article = []
art1 = []

#
#dd = soup.find("div", "art_author").text
#dd

filename = "scraped.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
#headers = "href;title;subtitle;time;article\n"
headers = "title;subtitle;time;article\n"
f.write(headers)


for url in list2:
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').decode('windows-1251')

    href = url
    title = soup.find("h1", "title").string
    #title = soup.find("h1", "title").string
    #title.extend(soup.find("h1", "title").string) # the title string
    subtitle = soup.find("div", "descr").string
    #subtitle.extend(soup.find("div", "descr").string) # the subtitle string
    time = soup.find("div", "art_author").text
    #time.extend(soup.find("div", "art_author").text)
    #par = soup.find("div", id="art_start").find_all("p")
    art1.extend(soup.find("div", id="art_start").find_all("p"))

    for a in art1:
        #article.extend(art1.find_all("p"))
        article = ([a.text.strip()])
        break

    #href = "".join(href)    
    title = "".join(title)
    subtitle = "".join(subtitle)
    time = "".join(time)
    article = "".join(article)

    #f.write(href + ";" + title + ";" + subtitle + ";" + time + ";" + article + "\n")
    f.write(title + ";" + subtitle + ";" + time + ";" + article +"\n")
f.close()
```

The main problem for now is that I get an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-12-9a796b182a82>", line 24, in <module>
    title = soup.find("h1", "title").string
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I can't really find a solution to this.

And the second problem is whenever I succeed scraping one site, some empty cells occur, which means I have to find a way through Ajax.

I use the Anaconda version 2018.12.

Comment: soup is not a BeautfulSoup object, but rather a string, which is why you get that error

Comment: and how can I leave it a bs object?

Comment: It has to do with the `.decode('windows-1251')` part. When you use the `.decode('windows-1251')`, it has your `soup` stored as a string. So working on how to alter that at the moment

Comment: Post the code along with your question. Not as a link to an external site.

Comment: Be careful, I do not know what you plan to do with your `list2` but if you modify either `list1` or `list2` both will be updated

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I fixed the issue with your `soup` object stored as a string, so you can use bs4 to parse the html. I also opted to use pandas `.to_csv()`, as I'm just more familiar with it, but it gets you the desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


# get the URL list
list1 = []

a = 'https://www.dnes.bg/sofia/2019/03/13/borisov-se-pohvali-prihodite-ot-gorivata-sa-sys-7-poveche.404467'
b = 'https://www.dnes.bg/obshtestvo/2019/03/13/pazim-ezika-si-pravopis-pod-patronaja-na-radeva.404462'
c = 'https://www.dnes.bg/politika/2019/01/03/politikata-nekanen-gost-na-praznichnata-novogodishna-trapeza.398091'
list1.append(a)
list1.append(b) 
list1.append(c) 
# define the variables
#url = "https://www.dnes.bg/politika/2019/01/03/politikata-nekanen-gost-na-praznichnata-novogodishna-trapeza.398091"
list2 = list1 #[0:10]
#type(list2)



results = pd.DataFrame()
for url in list2:

    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    href = url
    title = soup.find("h1", "title").text
    #title = soup.find("h1", "title").string
    #title.extend(soup.find("h1", "title").string) # the title string
    subtitle = soup.find("div", "descr").text
    #subtitle.extend(soup.find("div", "descr").string) # the subtitle string
    time = soup.find("div", "art_author").text
    #time.extend(soup.find("div", "art_author").text)
    #par = soup.find("div", id="art_start").find_all("p")
    art1 = soup.find("div", id="art_start").find_all("p")

    article = []
    for a in art1:
        if 'googletag.cmd.push' not in a.text:
            article.append(a.text.strip())
    article = ' '.join(article)



    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[title, subtitle, time, article]], columns = ['title','subtitle','time','article'])
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)

results.to_csv("scraped.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
                                               title                                           subtitle                                               time                                            article
0  Борисов се похвали: Приходите от горивата са с...  Мерките за изсветляване на сектора действат, к...  Обновена: 13 мар 2019 13:24 | 13 мар 2019 11:3...  Приходите от горивата са със 7% повече. Това с...
1  "Пазим езика си": Правопис под патронажа на Ра...  Грамотността зависи не само от училището, смят...  Обновена: 13 мар 2019 11:34 | 13 мар 2019 11:2...  За втора поредна година Сдружение "Живата вода...
2  Политиката – "неканен гост" на празничната нов...  Основателни ли бяха критиките на президента Ру...               3 яну 2019 10:45, Цветелин Димитров   Оказа ли се политиката "неканен гост" на празн...
```

Comment: Great! Works! Can't thank you enough for your time, really! 

Now I only have to figure out how to separate the column names with the delimiter I want to use - tab or ";".

Comment: with using pandas and dataframes with the `.to_csv()`, you wouldn't need that though. The columns are already seperated in the csv

Comment: I'll be importing it in another software for analysis. 

Skipping decode='windows-1251' produces another problem, so 
  encoding='windows-1251' makes it readable while writing.

But now the problem is that every line of the text within a cell is on new line.

Comment: I didn't notice until I started it that I receive the same text in the "article" column. So this script is not working as expected.

Comment: Ah yes. Ok. I think see where that issue is. I won’t be by my laptop until tomorrow and fix that.

Comment: Took a look. It has to do with art1.extend and the loop after that. I unfortunately can’t read the language and do not exactly which part is the article. So you’ll just have to clean up the bit to pull the specific parts that are the article for each iteration of the url list.

Comment: The article is within the part: 
d(soup.find("div", id="art_start").find_all("p"))

This class denotes the beginning of the article, and the p-s are the paragraphs. There is some garbage code between the p-s as adwords and others, marked with a <div>.
I just don't know why the same article appears on different URL-s.
Furthermore, I need to cope with the ajax functionality. :/

Comment: I'm thinking the same article is showing up for the different urls because it's just appending the articles on, then I'm having it pull article[0]. I made a s light change above. Try to run it again and see if this looks better

Comment: sorry, no. Body is separated on lines now... and the encoding is 'windows-1251'

Answer (score 0):

Something I stumbled upon ([here] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSH77vnOGqU ):

```
import bs4 as bs
import sys
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = ''
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        self.app.quit()



def main():
    page = Page('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'html.parser')
    js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
    print(js_test.text)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```